# search for a string

Tags: php

I want to search in large piece of texts for different strings and if the match found for each string it return me a special string (not the matched string).

there are almost 150 different string I want to search them in the thousand text files.
I write this code

```
foreach($countries as $cont)

{

    if(stripos($text,$cont))

    {

        $country=$cont;
```

and here is a few line of countries.php (I include this file) :

```
$countries['AD'] = 'Andorra';

$countries['AE'] = 'United Arab Emirates';

$countries['AF'] = 'Afghanistan';

$countries['AG'] = 'Antigua And Barbuda';

$countries['AI'] = 'Anguilla';

$countries['AL'] = 'Albania';
```

For example I want to print 'Arabian' when it was a match for 'United Arab Emirates'...

Comment: .:so, when you search for arabian, it will return United Arab Emirates? am i getting your point?

Answer (score 0):

take a look here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Pass each text to this function, alongside every match you're looking for (in an array) and another array where to put all the matches.

Then you can do whatever you want with all the matches you found.

Comment: Its a small part of my code and Its not the only thing I want to do in my program. Is there any other way for it ? I'll save $country in database and there are almost 15 different variable. so I prefer not to use preg_match for this one... looking for easier way

Comment: well, then next time please post all your requirements in the question :) I can't read your mind from here. I've trained for 1km radius, but I'm improving every day :D